# Is addLast method on channel pipeline blocking?

Tags: netty

I am dynamically adding and removing handlers to a channel pipeline, but seems like some times the call to the addLast method might not have finished adding the handler because my fairly immediate call c.pipeline.last() seems to be be giving back null. i am wondering if i need to do move this to some kind of future listner? i am using netty 4.1.27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit racy atm which means as long as you do these operation within the `EventLoop` thread it will be fine and just work while when doing it from other threads it may not be visibly directly. We plan to fix this in the next major version of netty by make all operations return a future.