# Channel pipeline addLast does not work sometimes

Tags: netty

Updating channel pipeline doesn't seem to thread-safe. Sometimes, especially when executed in a different thread, adding a handler to the channel pipeline and then firing a channel read event, isn't captured by the added channel handler. Eg:

**Doesn't Work**

```scala
new Thread(() => {
    ctx
        .channel()
        .pipeline()
        .addLast(H1)
        .addLast(H2)

    ctx.fireChannelRead(msg)
}).run()
```

**Temp Fix**

```scala
new Thread(() => {
    ctx
        .channel()
        .pipeline()
        .addLast(H1)
        .addLast(H2)

    // Works
    ctx.channel().eventLoop().submit(() => ctx.fireChannelRead(msg))
}).run()
```

Is there a better way to do fire a `channelRead` event? Couldn't this cause performance issues?

**Netty Version:** `4.1.63.Final`

Comment: Not 100% sure, but does ctx comes from an already defined handler ? If so, it starts from current handler. write is going up (to first handler), read is going down (to last handler). So, it looks like ok, since whatever the handler is, it is no more tha last one. However, the first example fire an event (ChannelRead) from the very same thread, while the second way uses a new "thread" from the eventLoop of the channel to make this event occurs in an asynchronous way. Maybe the reason? Does your code being within an Handler our outside?

Comment: ctx, comes from an already defined handler. In both cases I am using a `new Thread` but it's weird that the issue is only happening in the first case.

Comment: It might also be because of — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51644876/is-addlast-method-on-channel-pipeline-blocking?rq=1

But this is a very old question so I'm not sure if it's fixed.

Comment: What version of netty is this ?

Comment: @NormanMaurer `4.1.63.Final`

Comment: Could this be a bug?

Comment: Probably provide a full reproducer so that I can see what is going wrong. A casual try works for me.